# Error encountered: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm accessing oracle database which I'm a beginner on my api C#, when I try to execute my code, I'm encountering this error message according my exception handler "Value does not fall within the expected range". Would appreciate any inputs/corrections.

Oracle Code:

```
   create or replace PACKAGE BODY PKGFAETEST AS
   PROCEDURE CheckUser(uNAME IN VARCHAR2,
                 pWORD IN VARCHAR2,
                 po_refcsr OUT cursor_type)
   AS                 
   BEGIN 
   OPEN po_refcsr FOR
    SELECT
     A1.ID,
     A1.USERNAME,
     A1.PASS,
     A1.FIRSTNAME,
     A1.LASTNAME
    FROM
     FAE_TEST_USERS A1
    WHERE
     A1.USERNAME = uNAME
     AND A1.PASS = pWORD;
    END;
  END PKGFAETEST;
```

C# Code:

```
   public bool checkUser(string uName, string pWord)
    {
        bool result = false;
        try
        {
            string dbUName = string.Empty;
            string dbPWord = string.Empty;
            
            using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(TNS))
            {
                OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
                objCmd.Connection = conn;
                objCmd.CommandText = "PKGFAETEST.CheckUser";
                objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("uNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uName;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add("pWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pWord;
                conn.Open();
                using (OracleDataReader reader = objCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                            if (reader["USERNAME"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                dbUName = Convert.ToString(reader["USERNAME"]);
                            }
                            if (reader["PASS"] != DBNull.Value)
                            {
                                dbPWord = Convert.ToString(reader["PASS"]);
                            }
                            result = true;
                    }

                }

                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", e);
        }
        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem:

I just change this line of c# code:

```
     objCmd.Parameters.Add("uNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uName;
     objCmd.Parameters.Add("pWORD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pWord;
```

to:

```
      objCmd.Parameters.Add("uNAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = uName;
      objCmd.Parameters.Add("pWORD", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = pWord;
      objCmd.Parameters.Add("po_refcsr", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```